# how to use super().__add__ in a derived class

Tags: python, inheritance, operator-overloading

My code works but I'm not sure if this the correct way to implement it. I'm trying to use the base class "add" method in the derived class. `super().__add__` returns a base class therefore I must somehow "convert" the class back to the derived type before returning it. Can you please take a look and tell me if there is a better/ nicer way to implement this?

```
class a:
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def __repr__(self):
    return f"{self.x} {self.y}"

def __add__(self, other):
    return a(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)



class b(a):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.z = z

    def __repr__(self):
        str = super().__repr__()
        return str + f" {self.z}"

    def __add__(self, other):
        temp = super().__add__(other)
        new_z = self.z + other.z
        return b(temp.x, temp.y, new_z)
```

Thanks!
LI

Comment: `b` likely shouldn't be a subclass of `a` at all. What would `a(1, 2) + b(1, 2, 3)` return? What about `b(1, 2, 3) + a(1, 2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the constructor of class `b` compatible with that of the base class by making the additional parameter `z` optional with a default value:

```
class b(a):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z=0):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.z = z
```

so that the `__add__` method of the base class can instantiate a new object by the type of the `self` object rather than a hard-coded class:

```
class a:
    def __add__(self, other):
        return type(self)(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

and that the `__add__` method of the derived class can modify the object returned by the `__add__` method of the base class directly before returning it:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    temp = super().__add__(other)
    temp.z = self.z + other.z
    return temp
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/UnusedDraftyPortablesoftware